# Setting up Android OpenGl ES Environment fails

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to learn how to use OpenGL for Android. Therefore I followed [this](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html) guide to set up the environment. 
I have done everything like they say:
I got a `OpenGLActivity` which initiates my `MyGLSurfaceView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    glSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_gl);
}
```

This is my `MyGLSurfaceView`:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();

    // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
}
}
```

And Thats my `MyGLRenderder` class which should set the background to black:

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements Renderer {

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    // Redraw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
}
```

And I've added this line to my `AndroidManifest.xml` (right at the beginning, before `<application>` tag)

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

The problem is that the background isn't black, its white. 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually displaying your OpenGL view. In this code here:

```
glSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_gl);
```

you're setting the content view to be a view from your layout, while you're not using the `GLSurfaceView` you just created. It should be:

```
glSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
setContentView(glSurfaceView);
```